# Terminal shortcut key

Tags: 11.04, command-line, shortcut-keys

I liked the shortcut for opening a terminal and if I remember correctly it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> that opened a terminal window.

Now with a later version of Ubuntu this shortcut is no longer predefined, I must add it myself from the shortcut settings.

Do you know why this shortcut was removed?

Thanks for any answer
[image]

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The shortcut is still there for what I know.

There is perhaps some other application hiding that shortcut?

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is not assigned by default as a shortcut key in Natty Narwhal. You can assign it manually to open the Terminal though by using the "Keyboard Shortcuts" application.

Comment: It is Live CD. I also have 10.04 that I can boot to and see if the difference really depends on the version or something else. I updated the question with a screenshot. Rebooting from Live CD of Natty has a disabled shortcut for running a terminal. Hm...Thanks for answering and please comment more what you think the reason is my Live boot does this.

Comment: This is a conundrum :) All I can say is that this is not the first time something works one way on someone's box and another way on another person's box. I have see this before with numerous issues (e.g., whether video thumbnails preview or not). If you tap Super and type "ter" Terminal will come up in Dash at which point hitting enter will launch it. Perhaps developers considered this a simpler keyboard shortcut? And they figured for old school users they can always manually create Ctrl+Alt+T if they so desire? If I learn anything specific I'll report back ;)

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+T is assigned by default to launch Terminal in Oneiric.  For Natty you will have to add the shortcut manually.

Answer (score 3):

For 14.04 release, (for Unity) `unity-settings-daemon` or exactly its `media-keys` plugin  handles terminal launcher shortcut.

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/terminal
'<Primary><Alt>t'
```

System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Launch Terminal

[image]

(for Gnome) `gnome-settings-daemon` same as its fork `unity-settings-daemon`. Otherway using Compiz, it has a setting in *Gnome Compatibility* plugin:

`ccsm` → Gnome Compatibility → Commands → Open a terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not work by default in all desktop environments for example in Xubuntu it is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: not true. Lubuntu 14.04 always works

Comment: ok that does not negate my statement, though it is good to post that info in case someone was looking into this and wanted to know.